# Cocos2d-x Parallax with Accelerometer (How to stop smoothly when reaching the edges and when changing direction)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, accelerometer, parallax

I am creating a game that has 3 layers of background. They are added to a **CCParallaxNode** and it's moved by tilting the device to the right, left, up and down. I am using this code to move the CCParallaxNode (accelerometer delegate method - **didAccelerate**):

```
void SelectScreen::didAccelerate(cocos2d::CCAcceleration *pAccelerationValue)
{
    float deceleration = 0.1f, sensitivity = 30.0f, maxVelocity = 200;

    accelX = pAccelerationValue->x * sensitivity;
    accelY = pAccelerationValue->z * sensitivity;

    parallaxMovementX = parallaxMovementX * deceleration + pAccelerationValue->x * sensitivity;
    parallaxMovementX = fmaxf(fminf(parallaxMovementX, maxVelocity), -maxVelocity);

    float offset = -calibration * sensitivity;

    parallaxMovementY = (parallaxMovementY * deceleration + pAccelerationValue->z * sensitivity) + offset;
}
```

Then, in the **update** method:

```
void SelectScreen::update(float dt)
{
CCNode* node = getChildByTag(100);

    float maxX = (Data::getInstance()->getWinSize().width * 2) + 100;
    float minX = node->getContentSize().width - 100;

    float maxY = Data::getInstance()->getWinSize().height * 0.1f;
    float minY = -200;

    float diffX = parallaxMovementX;
    float diffY = parallaxMovementY;

    float newX = node->getPositionX() + diffX;
    float newY = node->getPositionY() + diffY;

    newX = MIN(MAX(newX, minX), maxX);

    newY = MIN(MAX(newY, minY), maxY);

    if(isUpdating)
        node->setPositionX(newX);
    if(isUpdatingY)
        node->setPositionY(newY);
}
```

The movement is nicely done, however, when reaching any of the 4 **edges** it **stops** **abruptly**. Also, when **changing direction** (eg. moving to the right then moving to the left) it does it **abruptly**.

**Question**: How can I do a smooth stop and a smooth direction change (maybe some little bouncing effect)? I think this is also related to the accelerometer data (when going fast it must bounce longer that it should when going slow).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need some math to smooth the movements.
Try checking the code here:
http://www.nscodecenter.com/preguntas/10768/3d-parallax-con-accelerometer